# Upload image windows phone and WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-7, file-upload

I'm creating a Windows phone application and the application is connected to a WCF server. The problem I have right now is the image upload function. Which function do I need to use? I can not find a answer to my problem.

Comment: are you uploading to WCF

Comment: I don't know, i just want to upload a image to a server so the image is available everywhere

Comment: Yes but do you have a service for it

Answer (score 1):

so you need to have a simple byte function on your WCF end

```
  [OperationContract]
    public void ReceiveByteArray(byte[] byteArray) { ... }
```

and convert your image to byte

```
public byte[] BufferFromImage(BitmapImage imageSource)
{        
    Stream stream = imageSource.StreamSource;
    byte[] buffer = null;

    if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

and then send your image

```
byte[] image=BufferFromImage(imageSource);
ReceiveByteArray(image)
```

Comment: Very nice solution, but how do i send the image to a folder in the server?

Comment: after you recive the image on your service just save it to a folder